# Can I drill a hole through brick wall/lintel for A/C lines?

Tags: foundation, brick

I'm looking to move the a/c refrigerant and return lines that are currently through the middle of a window opening to a more natural location so that a window can be installed in the opening.  I cleared out a 1" slot to relocate the a/c lines when I ran into a lintel in the top part of the window opening.  The idea of cutting the slot through the brick/foundation was to allow the a/c lines to move without calling somebody in to recapture the refrigerant.  I'll raise the a/c unit on a platform about 6" and the a/c lines will move up into that slot in the brick.

Now I am concerned that drilling a hole and then cutting entirely through the lintel with a reciprocating saw will weaken the integrity of the structure as it is supporting about 12' of bricks above.  The window opening is 30" wide.  The lintel can be viewed in the bottom of the slot that was cut but note that it extends into the brick wall about 6" as well and continues up into the brick (the back of the slot that was cut also is blocked by the lintel as it is L-shaped).

[image]

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Exchange. The lintel is supporting the window opening; things could get really entertaining if you cut it. Consider how much it might cost to repair that column of brick wall.

Comment: How high is this whole contraption? could you relocate lower and drill thru the (hopefully concrete) foundation?

Comment: I agree with your sense.   Severing a lintel is bad news.  Since you're in for a penny, in for a pound as it were, you might seize the opportunity to move the evaporator to somewhere that is in shade rather than direct sunlight, especially during the afternoons when A/C works hardest. The unit will run more efficiently if it is cooler, which will save you money.

Comment: Harper, I had an early start on this last weekend and the unit is installed on east side of house so by noon the unit is in the shade for the rest of the day.

Comment: Didn't realize <enter> would send my comments...wanted to thank everybody for their input and for (unfortunately) confirming my fears about the lentil and it's required usage.  The current line is about 26" above the driveway and the window opening is about 20" high by 30" wide.  I was thinking of framing in the opening to the right of the current line with at least 2x8's for the new window but I'll wind up just paying somebody to recapture the refrigerant.  Not sure I could mortar/brick in the 3-4" gap that would remain under the current line location and make it look pretty enough. Thx again

Comment: And I have as much trouble with lentils as I have with this window lintel.